# What does (N & S) abbreviation in restaurants in Berlitz English Course stand for? Picture included

Tags: meaning

In Berlitz English Course Level 3, Chapter 2. There's an exercise for the students to teach them how to discuss choosing a restaurant.

And there's a menu of some restaurants and in the cuisine column there's an (N & S) next to Italian. Please check the picture below.

What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: North and South. North is more like French cuisine, light or white sauces, and the south very heavy, with red tomato sauces.

Comment: Northern and Southern.  There is a cultural divide between Northern Italy and Southern Italy, and that includes a difference in typical cuisine.  "Italian (N&S)" is meant to indicate that the restaurant Zizi Trattoria serves cuisine of both Northern Italy and Southern Italy.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I don't know how to "upvote" your comments. So, I should at least post a thank you comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely ***North*** and ***South***.  Ofttimes, the cuisines of a single country are divided into one or more regions which can be quite different.  Italy [differs between the north and south](http://www.carlinosrestaurant.com/whats-the-difference-between-northern-and-southern-italian-food/); India and China also differ by region, as does the US.